# How change search operator in search feature in sugarcrm module

Tags: php, search, module, sugarcrm

I have trouble with search feature in sugarcrm modules, I always use **%-sign** in field box example: **%john** to show search result, i need only **john** not **%john**

I was edit my file at /modules/Accounts/Account.php at method:

```
function build_generic_where_clause ($the_query_string) {
    $where_clauses = Array();
    $the_query_string = $GLOBALS['db']->quote($the_query_string);
    array_push($where_clauses, "accounts.name like '%$the_query_string%' ");

    if (is_numeric($the_query_string)) {
        array_push($where_clauses, "accounts.phone_alternate like '%$the_query_string%'");
        array_push($where_clauses, "accounts.phone_fax like '%$the_query_string%'");
        array_push($where_clauses, "accounts.phone_office like '%$the_query_string%'");
    }
```

and edit /modules/Accounts/metadata/SearchFields.php at

```
'name' => array( 'query_type'=>'default', 'operator' => 'like'),
```

But Always fail,
Do you have solution for this?

---

**Solution**

> I edited my config.php and added `'search_wildcard_infront' => true`

Regards,
Rampak

Comment: solved, i was edit my config.php and add 'search_wildcard_infront' => true